# How do I fix this XML schema?

Tags: xsd

I am trying to use JAXB on my XML schema with IntelliJ Ultimate. This is the schema from the IndoorGML website. However, the IDE says there is something wrong with it.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/indoorgml/1.0/core"
       xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0.3">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
        IndoorGML is an OGC Standard. Copyright (c) 2014,2015,2016,2018 Open Geospatial Consortium. To obtain additional rights of use, visit http://www.opengeospatial.org/legal/.
    </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<!--
 ======================================================================
-->
<xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
<!--
 ======================================================================
-->
<xs:element name="IndoorFeatures" type="IndoorFeaturesType" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature"/>
<!--

</xs:schema>
```

In the last line in *substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature"*, the IDE marks *AbstractFeature* in red with the message "Cannot resolve symbol 'gml:AbstractFeature'". Does anyone know why? (The XSD file has more tags before the closing schema tag which I didnt' put here because it's a couple hundred lines.)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported error is on this reference: `substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature"`
...which is attempting make 'IndoorFeatures' a member of a substitution group that is defined in another namespace.

But which namespace? The namespace identified by the prefix 'gml'. And which namespace is that? The answer is here:  `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"`

So we need to find out where that namespace is imported into this XSD. That is done here:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
```

I think the reason for the error is fairly obvious now, but I will go ahead and complete the answer. The XSD which defines that namespace is identified here:
`schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"`

Clearly, your application cannot resolve that URL or is not allowed to access it.

**How can you fix it?**

If you can get a copy of the XSD then you can either

a) save it to a local folder and change the schemaLocation attribute to point to the local folder, or

b) Define a schema resolver that maps the URL to your folder location.

Not sure whether IntelliJ supports schema resolvers, but I expect it does.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem in that particualar xsd file. However, when I put the missing schema in the local folder, it then again says that there are missing xsd files. So I put those again in the folder. Those files again need other xsd files, which I put in the folder. Those files again need other xsd files. It's a never ending story. Do I have to keep doing it until I have hundreds of xsd files in my folder or is there a better way to include all xsd files that are needed to use my first original xsd file?

Comment: If the schema is constructed from 100s of individual XSDs then IntelliJ will need to get access to them all. Usually this is done by downloading a zip file provided by the standards body that created the schema.